# How to speed up query for stock balance?

Tags: sql-server, performance, query

I have 2 tables `StockIn` and `StockOut` and calculated stock balance (in-out).

Both tables contain millions of records.

When I calculate the stock balance, due to the millions of records, my query crashes.

Can anybody help me to speed up or fix this query?

```sql
SELECT Main.Item, SUM(Main.Qty) AS Qty
FROM     (SELECT item, Qty
                  FROM      StockIn
                   UNION ALL
                  SELECT item, -Qty
                  FROM     Stockout) AS Main 
GROUP BY Main.Item
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried creating columnstore index? Also provide details of your specification of SQL Server, memory and CPU/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the subtotals of all stock in and stock out separately, then sum them to get the balance.

```
SELECT Main.Item, SUM(Main.Qty) AS Qty FROM 
    (SELECT item, SUM(Qty) as Qty FROM StockIn GROUP BY item
     UNION ALL 
     SELECT item, -SUM(Qty) as Qty FROM Stockout GROUP BY item) 
    AS Main 
GROUP BY Main.Item
```

Also make sure that both tables are indexed on the `item` column

Comment: Dear Andrea prior when the records in thousand query well work but now records in millions so query crash, can u tell how can faster query in million or billion records